# Is there any way to convert html to pdf converter without headless browser on node.js enviroment?

Tags: node.js, html-to-pdf

I want to convert html code to pdf file(on buffer). and then upload to s3 cloud.

found ways

1. puppeteer <- it has chromium dependency issue, I can't use chromium with pm2
2. pdfkit <- it doesn't support html convert.

That's all... is there any way?

Comment: What's issue you're facing when using puppeteer with pm2?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this node package: [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf).
It seems to be working, but unfortunately it is marked as deprecated.
Installing it with npm i was enough, no headless browsers needed.

Comment: Thanks! 
It' looks good, but I want to use module without headless browser;;